# Using byte[] to convert images in jpeg or bmp on android

Tags: android, javax.imageio

I know of using ImageIO on Java.

```
ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

I don't have access to this class on android 2.2.

Does anyone know a jar file which would allow me to convert byte array to jpg or bmp? or can someone provide me another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) class, especially the `decodeByteArray()`-method.

Comment: Do you know  how you should do it if for jpeg. I have tried:
        try{
         byte[] hey = bookLoaded().getCoverImage().getData();
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(hey, 0, hey.length);
         image_view.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
         e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Somehow it doesn't display anything.

Comment: 1: what is bookLoaded() and getCoverImage() returning? 2: add something in your catch-block to make sure you don't get an exception.

Comment: I am using another jar to get image from an epub book which is the method bookloaded(). There are not errors in bookloaded method and on debug state it is confirmed that there is a value on bmp and byte[] hey. I am not certain if the file not being bmp should make a difference. Since it is a jpeg file inside it.

Comment: Also make sure that the resulting Bitmap (`bmp`) is not null. If it is null, BitmapFactory failed to parse it, otherwise something could be wrong with the parsed result.

Comment: It's not a bmp, more like a .jpeg. I checked the epub folder. For bmp, bmp is not null I did check that bytes did consist inside of it. However I am not certain if jpeg files work on bitmapfactory.

Comment: This must be the epub.library issue. Thanks a lot. I tried out BitmapFactory before but since the the devs didn't show if they supported jpeg or any other images I automatically assumed that they don't.

Comment: You can read a little bit more about supported formats for BitmapFactory in the docs for Bitmap, if you look at the compress()-method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29